# converting a file of numbers in to a list

Tags: python

to put it simply i am trying to read a file that will eventually have nothing but numbers in them either seperated by spaces, commas, or new lines. I have read through alot of these post and fixed somethings. I learned they are imported as strings first. however i am running into an issue where its importing the numbers as list. so now i have a list of list. this would be fine except i cant have it checked by ints or have numbers added to it. the idea is to have each user asigned a number and then saved. im not worrying about saving right now im just worried about importing the numbers and being able to use them as individual numbers.

my code thus far:

```
fo1 = open('mach_uID_3.txt', 'a+')

t1 = fo1.read()
t2 = []

print t1

for x in t1.split():
    print x
    z = [int(n) for n in x.split()]
    t2.append(z)


print t2
print t2[3]

fo1.close()
```

and the file its reading is.

```
0 1 2 25
34
23
```

my results are pretty ugly but here you go.

```
0 1 2 25
34
23

0
1
2
25
34
23
[[0], [1], [2], [25], [34], [23]]
[25]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: So what do you want it to do instead? Its creating a list of list because you are generating a new list `z = [int(n) for n in x.split()]` then adding it to your results `t2.append(z)` - not sure why you were expecting something else?

Comment: you  my friend just pointed out my problem. thank you good sir. dont know how i kept over looking that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extend` instead of `append`:

```
t2.extend(int(n) for n in x.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

To have all the numbers in a single, flattened list, do this:

```
fo1 = open('mach_uID_3.txt', 'a+')

number_list = list(map(int, fo1.read().split())

fo1.close()
```

But it's better to open the file like this:

```
with open('mach_uID_3.txt', 'a+') as fo1:
    number_list = list(map(int, fo1.read().split())
```

so you don't have to explicitly close it.